# Unpermitted parameter when trying to update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models, `ProjectCategory` and `ProjectQuestion`. A `ProjectCategory` can have many questions related to it, and a `ProjectQuestion` can only have one category related to it.

I have a form letting the user edit a question, including what category (if any) it's related to. When I submit the form however, I get the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: project_category_id
```

However in the `ProjectQuestion` controller I have the permit method configured like so:

```
params.require(:project_question).permit(:title, :project_category_id)
```

I can't figure out how to let me set the foreign key. All the SO answers I've found so far only show the situation where you're creating the relationship on the parent side which isn't what I want.

### That data being sent to the server seems to be correct:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/questions/2" for ::1 at 2017-04-21 16:45:19 +1000
Processing by AdminController#update_project_question as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9Abl7Rruj/5LD4/rI/WKlQ8MQ8eY/TMVFUaw53kfFw199xFekfzgyiWZytzsJ5qHU+edNpoqhXG5xWvuzHFP7g==", "project_question"=>{"title"=>"What are the images not telling us testing", "project_category_id"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Update Project question", "id"=>"2"}
```

### This is how the field is set in the view:

```
<%= f.label 'Category' %>
<%= f.select :project_category_id, options_for_select(ProjectCategory.all.map{|s|[s.title, s.id]}) %>
```

### Here is my `ProjectCategory` model:

```
class ProjectCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  has_many :project_questions

  validates_presence_of :title

end
```

### And here is my `ProjectQuestion` model:

```
class ProjectQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entry_project_questions
  validates_presence_of :title, :project_category_id
  belongs_to :project_category

end
```

This is my first Ruby project so I'm still learning, but I've been unable to figure out what I'm missing to get this to work properly.

Comment: Seems like you are not using the strong-params while updating the model

Comment: can you please the controller method where you are updating and also the strong params method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Christopher Muller,

You are processing the request through AdminController, whereas you have put permit in ProjectQuestion. Please add the code to AdminController where the processing is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue! I appreciate the help. Sounds so obvious now that I read it.